# ifdraft package stops page compilation after upgrade to TexLive 2020

Tags: errors, draftwatermark

I've been preparing a document, which uses the `ifdraft` package to include a watermark. Compilation has been fine up until today before I upgraded my installation from TexLive 2019 to TexLive 2020 using the MacTex distribution. The compilation now fails with a `! Package keyval Error: 223 defined.` error. I'm compiling with `lualatex` on the command-line and VIM ex: mode.

Initially, I put it down to the combination of packages I've used, however, I've created a sample file using only `ifdraft`, `blindtext` and `draftwatermark`, which likewise fails:

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ifdraft, blindtext}
\ifoptiondraft{%
  \usepackage{draftwatermark}
  \SetWatermarkText{DRAFT}
  \SetWatermarkScale{1}
  \SetWatermarkColor[rgb]{0.7,0,0}
}{%
  % nothing to see here
}
\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Compiling from VIM with `:lualatex %`, or the terminal, gives the output:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)
 restricted system commands enabled.
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
 L3 programming layer <2020-04-06>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/ifdraft.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/blindtext/blindtext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/xspace.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/draftwatermark/draftwatermark.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/everypage/everypage.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)))

! Package keyval Error: 223 undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...
l.10 }
```

I've tried including a package specification in the "else/final" clause so it wasn't empty in case that was the fault, but when `draft` is included in `documentclass`, the above error occurs without fail. The closing brace is highlighted each time.

Perhaps someone could give me a pointer where I should be looking. I'm at a bit of loss where to look.

Comment: the error is not from ifdraft but from `\SetWatermarkColor[rgb]{0.7,0,0}`.

Comment: Use `\definecolor{wmc}{rgb}{0.7,0,0}\SetWatermarkColor{wmc}` instead of `\SetWatermarkColor[rgb]{0.7,0,0}`

Comment: The error is not specific to luatex

Comment: the setting of colors with a specification is broken, there is a brace pair missing and the colors are not correctly expanded later. Make a bug report.

Comment: Your help narrowing it down to `\SetWatermarkColor`, I realised changing the colour model to `gray` worked. The problem definitely lies with the `rgb` model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in `draftwatermark`, when it passes the `colorspec` option without any protection against interpreting commas in the color specification.

You can work around it by loading `xcolor` and bracing the color specification.

```latex
\documentclass[draft,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ifdraft, blindtext,xcolor}
\ifoptiondraft{%
  \usepackage{draftwatermark}
  \SetWatermarkText{DRAFT}
  \SetWatermarkScale{1}
  \SetWatermarkColor[rgb]{{0.7,0,0}}
}{%
  % nothing to see here
}
\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you @egreg. Why does the additional bracing work?

Comment: `\SetWatermarkColor` passes another macro the option `colorspec=#2`, which in your case becomes `colorspec=0.7,0,0` and the `0` becomes an option, whence the strange error.