# SetWatermarkColor does not work with TeX Live 2020

Tags: texlive-2019, texlive-2020, draftwatermark

I am using XeLaTeX compiler on TeX Live version 2020 on overleaf.com.

The below MWE does not compile on TeX Live version 2020.

It works perfectly on TexLive version 2019.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkLightness{0.5}
\SetWatermarkColor[rgb]{1,0.75,0.75}
\SetWatermarkText{\mdseries PROOF}
\SetWatermarkFontSize{3.5cm}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

The error I get in TeX Live 2020 is "Package keyval Error: 0.75 undefined".

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/540961/2388. And better notify the author, he should correct this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need the Package *xcolor* for colored Watermarks.
You might also try *DraftwatermarkOptions* inside the document.
More about DraftWatermarkOptions you can find here: ["The draftwatermark package∗" by Sergio Callegari](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/draftwatermark/draftwatermark.pdf)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{\mdseries PROOF}
\begin{document}
  \DraftwatermarkOptions{color={[RGB]{255,191,191}}}
  \DraftwatermarkOptions{fontsize=3.5cm}
  \blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```